# Asp.net and Ext.Net validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, ext.net

Does anybody show me an example of ext.net validation? I want to mix asp.net and ext.net validation. Or use ext.net validation only.

I've already saw these examples http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/Validation/Custom_VType/ and http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/FormPanel/Validation/ but it's not enough.

Also, I wonder why the code bottom doesn't work. It throws an exception

> "Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place. It
>   should be queried in the event handler for a control that has
>   CausesValidation=True and initiated the postback, or after a call to
>   Page.Validate"

```
<script runat="server">

        void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // Display whether the page passed validation.
            if (Page.IsValid) {
                Label1.Text = "Page is valid.";
            }
            else {
                Label1.Text = "Page is not valid!";
            }
        }

        void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
            try {
                // Test whether the value entered into the text box is even.
                int i = int.Parse(args.Value);
                args.IsValid = ((i % 2) == 0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }

    </script>
    <ext:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter an even number:" />
    <br />
    <ext:TextField ID="TextField1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextField1" OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
        ErrorMessage="Not an even number!" />
    <ext:Button runat="server" Text="Validate" >
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click OnEvent="Button_Click" />
        </DirectEvents>
    </ext:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this sample? And in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hGCjnNqh

```
<script runat="server">
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    Page.Validate();

}

void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        // Test whether the value entered into the text box is even.
        int i = int.Parse(args.Value);
        args.IsValid = ((i % 2) == 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}

void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Display whether the page passed validation.
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        Label1.Text = "Page is valid.";
    } else {
        Label1.Text = "Page is not valid!";
    }
}
```

```
<ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" />
<ext:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter an even number:" />
<br/>
<ext:TextField ID="TextField1" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextField1"
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidation" 
    ErrorMessage="Not an even number!" />
<ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validate" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="true">
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click OnEvent="Button_Click" />
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

Comment: I want to do it without postback.

Comment: Maybe you look here http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?9729-CLOSED-1.0-Equivalent-to-ASP.NET-custom-validator. Post before last describes validation without postback?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you exactly.

Comment: You want to validate after button click or on field change?

Comment: A little remark. I want to do it after button click, but without post back (by DirectEvent).

Comment: I have not tried it yet. When I try one, I'll tell you. Thanks anyway.

Comment: <<Is this code help you?>> Your question is not correct. It must be: Does this code help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use ext.net component inside ext.net formpanel  you don t need to use asp net validation.